# How do you force ordering of messages in an Azure Service Bus queue or topic?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there already a native solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Service Bus [message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).
For the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK, here's an [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample05_SessionProcessor.md).

The blanket statement about avoiding ordered messaging is not wrong in general, but there are scenarios were order must be guaranteed. Message sessions is a native ASB feature providing that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Exactly, there are some scenarios order must be guaranteed. In my case, image customer(member) change his name from "xyz" to "foo" first and right after that to "bar". 2 events are published, CustomerUpdated & CustomerUpdated. The first one has Name = "Foo" and the other one has Name = "Bar". And if the "Bar" one is processed before the "Foo" for a reason, the latest state in the database will hold the "Foo" which is wrong. The similar scenario occurs for ScheduledAppointments (members change their appointments 2 times).